# Prove validity of argument

Tags: logic

I am trying to prove the validity of the following argument:

1. (p $\rightarrow$ q) $\land$ (r $\rightarrow$ s)
2. p $\lor$ r

Therefore:

3. q $\lor$ s

I am stuck pretty early on. I removed the implications on line #1 by using logical equivalences, and now have the following:

1. (~p $\lor$ q) $\land$ (~r $\lor$ s)

I'm not sure how I can further simplify this argument?

Comment: What is your list of rules of inference?

Comment: @DougSpoonwood more or less the list here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rules_of_inference#Table:_Rules_of_Inference

Comment: Statement 1. is a conjunction.  What rules of inference can you use on a conjunction?  Statement 2. is a disjunction.  What rules of inference can you use on a disjunction?  Also, can any sub-wff (sub well-formed formula) of 1. or 2. imply the conclusion by itself?

Comment: @DougSpoonwood That's what I'm stuck on for this one. I have worked through several questions in my text book and then reached this one (which unfortunately does not have any worked solution). It seems like it should be simple, but I can't see where to go.

Comment: Have you tried assuming any of the subwffs of 1. or 2. seeing what you can derive, and then using conditional introduction?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Start appling *Simplification* (or *Conjunction Elimination*) to 1st premise to derive :

a) $(p → q)$

b) $(r → s)$

Then apply *Case analysis* with 2nd premise to derive by *Modus ponens*, follwed by *Addition* (or *Disjunction Introduction*), from the two formulas above :

> c) $q \lor s$.